# What are the attributes of the `msg` object and how can I list them?

Tags: solidity

I know `msg.sender` exists, it gives the address of the sender. What other attributes are there and how can I list them / where are they defined?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties

```
msg.data (bytes): complete calldata
msg.gas (uint): remaining gas
msg.sender (address): sender of the message (current call)
msg.sig (bytes4): first four bytes of the calldata (i.e. function identifier)
msg.value (uint): number of wei sent with the message
```